# Setting default_timezone on a single model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, timezone, rails-activerecord, utc

I've got an issue reading from a database that's fed from other system, as in I just can read from it, and has datetime stored in :local timezone.

As with Rails 3.2 apps, it "should" be stored in :utc as all my other tables in this app.

**I need just this model to be in :local. The rest have to be in :utc**

My local timezone is 'UTC -04:00'

```
class ExternalTable < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection :otherdb
  table_name :iseries_table  <-- I have to live with it.
  default_timezone = :local
  puts "my default timezone is #{default_timezone}"

  #lot's of defs
   .....
end
```

Running "rails c"

```
> ExternalTable.inspect
«lot´s of attributes»
my default timezone is :utc  <---utc!?. I have just set it to :local!?!?!?

> ExternalTable.default_timezone 
:utc

> ExternalTable.default_timezone = :local
:local

> ExternalTable.default_timezone 
:local  <--- yeah, right. Setting it AFTER instantiated, works.
```

So, it seems Rails is setting all ActiveRecord.Base timezone back to :utc, after it is initialized, overriding ActiveRecord's default, that is :local.

There are a lot's of ways to go arround this, such as setting a before_filter on every controller , but it just doesn't seem Rubyist like.

Comment: I have the same problem, only in reverse - need just one model to be `:utc`

Comment: What makes this hard is that default_timezone is a [class attribute](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/default_timezone/class). Set it in on one model and it applies to your other models too.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't it be:

```
self.default_timezone = :local
```

Otherwise you are creating a local variable called "default_timezone".

If you just want it to apply to one class you could create a singleton method:

```
class ExternalTable < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.default_timezone
    :local
  end
end
```

A little hackish but should work.

Comment: This is right, but it doesn't do what he wants. The problem is that default_timezone is a class attribute, so it will apply to all ActiveRecord models, not just the one he sets it on.

Comment: Agreed on the first example.  But, in the second example, the class is ExternalTable.  So, class variables should only impact tables of that particular class.  Right?

Comment: Depends on how default_timezone is defined. Rails uses cattr_accessor(http://apidock.com/rails/Class/cattr_accessor). This is a shared value among all subclasses of the parent class. Change it anywhere and it changes for everyone.

If they had used class_attribute(http://apidock.com/rails/Class/class_attribute) then it would behave as you describe. But they didn't. So instead my example just monkey-patches default_timezone on just the subclass to provide a entirely new definition that just returns a hard-coded value.

Comment: This actually doesn't appear to work, ActiveRecord hard-codes Base.default_timezone in a few places. Still good for the bounty if it turns out to be actually impossible.

Comment: Doesn't surprise me. May be why it used cattr_accessor instead of class_attribute. You could submit a patch that removes the hard-codes, but there may be weird edge cases with using models in different time zones anyway so it may not be worth it.

Comment: this is terrible and there should be a way.  :(  I'm dealing with connecting to a legacy database that requires I add times in local time, but my rails db is all nice and UTC.  Rails should provide an easy way to override the time for a specific field in a specific model.

Comment: @don.najd, are you still searching a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 6, you can already write as your question, which will set every class inherited from BiLocalTimeRecord, datetime as local time:

```rb
    module Bi
      class BiLocalTimeRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
        self.abstract_class = true
        self.default_timezone = :local
        establish_connection :cybros_bi
      end
    end
```